# while uploading heavy images, server takes too much time and then it gives blank page(nginx, rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

When I upload heavy / more than 6 images, nginx server goes down and it gives blank page. what should I do in this case? Is there any configuration needed for nginx?

Comment: At least you should show us your nginx configuration, your application server (e.g. puma, passenger, ...) configuration and your Rails  controllers (maybe models too, depending on whether you have image post-processes).

Comment: [`client_max_body_size`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)

Answer (score 2):

Use client_max_body_size 100M; Also increase the timeout.

nginx error log will indicate the root cause. Please check that too